# What phrases exist which are apparently contradictory, but actually mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning

I have several items of clothing for which their dark colours could run on washing.

Some have a warning label in that says 'wash dark colours together'. Some have a label that says 'wash dark colours separately'. These apparently contradictory labels actually tell me to do the same thing, when context is taken into account.

What other examples are there, either out in the wild, or that could be constructed, of opposite messages meaning the same thing?

Comment: This glas is half-full – this glas is half-empty.

Comment: "The road up and the road down are one and the same... Also, the road is closed for construction."

Comment: *flammable* and *inflammable*

Comment: Bad means good. http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/12/bad.html

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320260/term-for-phrases-which-are-synonymous-as-a-whole-but-antonymous-on-a-literal-rea/329127#329127  In that other question i suggested "paradoxical heteronym", which was accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Although, thinking about it again, I think that *"paradoxical paraphrase"* is actually better.

Comment: Another one used around computers is **"worse is better"** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better